# Was Solomon interested in studying the Scriptures?

Tags: torah, solomon

> 1 Kings 4:29-34 (NIV)
>
> God gave Solomon wisdom and very great insight, and a breadth of
>   understanding as measureless as the sand on the seashore. Solomon’s
>   wisdom was greater than the wisdom of all the people of the East, and
>   greater than all the wisdom of Egypt. He was wiser than anyone else,
>   including Ethan the Ezrahite—wiser than Heman, Kalkol and Darda, the
>   sons of Mahol. And his fame spread to all the surrounding nations. He
>   spoke three thousand ***proverbs*** and his ***songs*** numbered a thousand and
>   five. He spoke about ***plant life***, from the cedar of Lebanon to the
>   hyssop that grows out of walls. He also spoke about ***animals and birds,
>   reptiles and fish***. From all nations people came to listen to Solomon’s
>   wisdom, sent by all the kings of the world, who had heard of his
>   wisdom.

Solomon was great indeed. Here I can at least see 4 different subjects where he is interested in; **Literature, Poetry, Botany, Zoology** . Great. But what about **Theology**! This makes me wonder, was Solomon interested in reading the Torah? The five books of Moses were already there and there are many interesting things in there. It might be possible that he revered the Torah so much that he never thought of studying it? There were also other books like Samuel, Judges, Ruth and others. He met with the God of Israel at least two times and God gave him wisdom and wealth, but still his wives could turn his heart after other gods.

Was Solomon interested in knowing God? Was he interested in studying the scriptures at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solomon pursued pleasure, knowledge, fame and wealth in his life. He disobeyed the rules for the king of Israel given by God through Moses.

> *Deuteronomy 17:16-19 (NIV)* The king, moreover, **must not acquire great numbers of horses** for himself or make the people return to Egypt
>   to get more of them, for the Lord has told you, “You are not to go
>   back that way again.” He **must not take many wives**, or his heart will
>   be led astray. He **must not accumulate large amounts of silver and
>   gold**. When he takes the throne of his kingdom, **he is to write for
>   himself on a scroll a copy of this law**, taken from that of the
>   Levitical priests. It is to be with him, and **he is to read it all the
>   days of his life** so that he may learn to revere the Lord his God and
>   follow carefully all the words of this law and these decrees

Solomon acted against the Law of Moses.

> *1 Kings 11:3* He had seven hundred wives of royal birth and three
>   hundred concubines, and his wives led him astray.
>
> *1 Kings 10:26* Solomon accumulated chariots and horses; he had fourteen
>   hundred chariots and twelve thousand horses, which he kept in the
>   chariot cities and also with him in Jerusalem.
>
> *1 Kings 10:14* The weight of the gold that Solomon received yearly was
>   666 talents

Later in his life, Solomon regretted and said that everything he did in his life was meaningless. He realized that he should have spent his life reading the Scripture.

> *Ecclesiastes 12:8 (NIV)* “Meaningless! Meaningless!” says the Teacher.
>       “Everything is meaningless!”
>
> *Ecclesiastes 12:13 (NIV)* Now all has been heard;
>       here is the conclusion of the matter: Fear God and keep his commandments,
>       for this is the duty of all mankind.

Answer (score 1):

> *Proverbs 1:1*
> The proverbs of Solomon the son of David, king of Israel;
>
> *Proverbs 4:20-23*
> My son, attend to my words;
> incline thine ear unto my sayings.
> Let them not depart from thine eyes;
> keep them in the midst of thine heart.
> For they are life unto those that find them,
> and health to all their flesh.
> Keep thy heart with all diligence;
> for out of it are the issues of life.
>
> *Proverbs 21:2-4*
> Every way of a man is right in his own eyes:
> but the LORD pondereth the hearts.
> To do justice and judgment
> is more acceptable to the LORD than sacrifice.
> An high look, and a proud heart,
> and the plowing of the wicked, is sin.

Yes Solomon wrote the book a Proverbs which magnifies God's wisdom in the seemingly small and yet altogether important things.

Comment: Out of all the verses you mentioned, only Prov 21:3 looks similar with the Scripture, 1 Samuel 15:22 "_To obey is better than sacrifice_" but still not close enough.

Comment: @Mawia I'm sorry I just thought you didn't know that Solomon wrote proverbs I didn't realize you rejected the validity of Proverbs, Lamentations and Song of Solomon as scripture. My point was the originator of scripture must have been studious in scripture regardless of what the scripture itself is discussing.

Comment: I am not rejecting the works of Solomon but when I look at his life as recorded in the Book of Kings, I somehow doubt about his piety or faithfulness to Jehovah.

Comment: My assumption is that, if he was studious in scripture, then he could have wrote many good commentaries about the Creation, Fall of man, the Flood etc..

Comment: @Mawia but the Lord did not want to use him to write about those topics. The Lord wanted to use him for another purpose. The eye though it is different than the ear is still a part of the body and equally necessary. If all solomon did was study the topics of his own books that would still be studying the scripture.

Comment: @caseyr547 - Lamentations was written by Jeremiah, not Solomon. Did you mean Ecclesiastes?